# How to get the value of a type

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to get the value of a type in my code. There is a x which is a stmt and the value is ("x" 1).
I want to get that "x" and use it as a key to find a value in a hashtable.
What I am asking is how to extract the "x".

```
type variable = string
type expr = int
type arrayref = variable * expr
type stmt = Dim of arrayref
let x = Dim("x",1);;

let aa (sbc:stmt) = match sbc with
|Dim a -> None;;
```

I should replace None to some codes, but no idea how to do that.

Comment: The question is misleading, A type has no value. Maybe a better title would be: How to extract components of a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but I think you're asking how to access a component of a compound value. For tuples and variants, the way to do this is with pattern matching. So you have that right. You just need to make your pattern a little deeper. To get the `"x"` from your value `x` you would do something like this:

```
let extracted_value =
    match x with
    | Dim (k, _) -> k
in
. . .
```

Since there is only one constructor in your `stmt` type (at least right now), you can do this without a match as follows:

```
let Dim (extracted_value, _) = x in
. . .
```

This works because there is a single pattern that is exhaustive. For types with more constructors you need to use `match` to handle all the possibilities.

If this isn't what you're asking, maybe try asking again in a different way.

**Update**

To print the string you could write something like this:

```
let Dim (k, _) = x in print_string k
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused about how to do that without a match. For example I have  match x with
    | Dim (k, _) ->  print_string k. How to do the same thing without a match even though I only have one constructor. Thank you.